# writing polynomials from roots

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to write an expression that represents $ p(x) $ a third degree polynome such that:
$$ p(x) = 0 \Leftrightarrow x = -3 \lor x = 1 \lor x = 2 $$ and $$
p(0) = 2 $$

I can't seem to get past the second condition since if $$ p(x) = (x+3)(x-1)(x-2) \Leftrightarrow p(0) = 6 $$
any thoughts? 
thanks in advance!

Comment: Try multiplying your polynomial with a real number. $\frac{1}{3}$, for example. Does that change where the zeros are?

Comment: Notice that you are *not* told that the polynomial is monic!

Answer (score 0):

what about

$p(x) = \frac{1}{3} (x+3)(x-1)(x-2)$?

You just forgot about the pre-factor!

Comment: yup! you're right! I guess i'm just tired and completely missed that! thanks a lot!